# Python/Java: How to Reverse a String Words but not special characters

Tags: python, string, special-characters, reverse

I have an input string with Special characters:
input= "the: sky is sunny"
expected output = "sunny: is sky the"

Need to reverse a string words but preserving special char in string.

I have done simple string reverse, but that did not preserve the special characters :(
Please help how to do this ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: your expected result did not preserve the special character either. original special character was at position 3 (0-indexed) and in your expected result the special character was at position 5 (0-indexed)........ your requirements are unclear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `re`:

```
s1 = 'the: sky is sunny'
fmt = re.sub(r'\w+', '{}', s1)
s2 = fmt.format(*reversed(re.findall(r'\w+', s1)))
```

```
>>> s2
'sunny: is sky the'
```

Regex: `\w+`

`\w`: matches any word character (equivalent to [a-zA-Z0-9_])

`+`: matches the previous token between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)

*Source: https://regex101.com/*

Comment: That use of `fmt` is very nice +1

Comment: Thank you !  Can you please help me understanding the regex. ?